# Is trend data related to tags available?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think I recall seeing somewhere that after a certain reputation level users get access to things like site analytics/data etc. I was curious if this means that high-reputation users have data on trends in particular tag usage?

I would be interested to see if there was some sort of trend data related to increasing/decreasing usage of certain tags. For example, it seems like tags like [tensorflow](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow) are falling and [pytorch](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pytorch) might be rising rapidly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sort of information is freely available in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE); for example:
https://data.stackexchange.com/datascience/query/1714507/tag-question-counts-graph#graph

[Access to site analytics](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) is unlocked at 5000 reputation, but doesn't have this level of detail anyway.

Comment: This is great! Seems like the data seems to validate my theory that an increase in PyTorch usage has coincided with a decline in TensorFlow usage. Fascinating.

Comment: @Ethan pretty clear trend in both academia and industry. Can be validated by looking at GitHub or publications.